# Resultset.getBoolean()) not returning true for if condition - row has value

Tags: java

Resultset.getBoolean()) not returning true, when value is there.

I'm trying to use a if condition so if there is row value in "fldplayersalary" then enter condition, however it keeps going to else. I have put a breakpoint and there is value for fldplayersalary (15583 for example).

Can someone explain why the .getBoolean is not returning true, because there is definitely a field "fldplayersalary" in table and data also. I've attached a screenshot of MySQL database

[image of sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh6xp.png)

```
               ResultSet r = stm.executeQuery("select * from tblmember");
                
                //1-int,2-string,3-string,
                
                
                
                while(r.next())
                {
                    
                    if(r.getBoolean("fldplayersalary") == true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player - 11 fields");
                       
                        int id = r.getInt("fldmemberid");
                        String first = r.getString("fldfirstname");
                        String last = r.getString("fldlastname");
                        String email = r.getString("fldemail");
                        String mob = r.getString("fldmobile");
                        String gender = r.getString("fldgender");
                        String dob = r.getString("flddob");
                        String debut = r.getString("flddebut");
                        String recruited = r.getString("fldrecruitedfrom");
                        int salary = r.getInt("fldplayersalary");
                        int team =  r.getInt("fldteamid");
                        
                        Player pp = new Player(id, first, last, email, mob, gender, dob, debut, recruited, salary, team);
                        plist.add(pp);
                        
                        
                    }
```

Comment: Have you read the [ResultSet API #getBoolean(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String)) section? If so, is anything unclear about why this *should* be returning false?

Comment: Is there a .getBooleanString() or something, so if there is a string present return true but if there is NULL then return false?

Comment: No. If the field is a boolean field and holds a value of TRUE, then it will return true. If there is a CHAR or VARCHAR that holds a value of "1" it will return true, otherwise, if it is not "0" or "1" it may throw an exception. Your SQL doesn't appear to satisfy any of the requirements that should make it return a boolean value of true. Please re-read the API.

Answer (score 0):

`.getBoolean` is for reading boolean values, hence the name.

You seem to believe that the concept of truthy/falsy is universal. It isn't. First, adjust your thinking, then this becomes much simpler.

'truthy'/'falsy' is the notion that all expressions, if forcibly interpreted as a boolean, always report one of those two values. Many programming languages and environments are completely truthy/falsy, such as javascript and python.

**However, java is not**. In java, `true` is true, `false` is false, and **nothing else is**:

```
String x = "true";
if (x) {}
```

simply fails to compile in java, as `x` is neither the boolean value `true` nor the boolean value `false` (specifically, the type of the expression `x` isn't boolean, and the compiler immediately calls it at that point and flags an error). You appear to be so used to languages that have this complicated definition of what is considered 'true' (truthy) and what is considered 'false' (falsy), such as 'lists are truthy unless empty, null and undefined are falsy, numbers are truthy unless 0 or NaN, strings are truthy unless empty, nobody can remember if the string "false" or "0" is truthy or falsy, objects are truthy unless they override an operator method to say they are falsy, even a boolean wrapper wrapping the value 'false' ends up being truthy because of that, yadayada'. Hopefully you now also know why truthy/falsy is not universally applied: It's quite confusing at times. Java doesn't engage in it; java doesn't ever guess what you intended when you pass a non-boolean to a thing where only booleans are allowed. It just errors and demands you perform an operation that explicitly resolves to a boolean value, such as `a < b` or `a.foo()` where `foo()` has `boolean` as return type, etc.

Now that you know such systems exist, it should be obvious that the meaning of `getBoolean` is not 'act like python or javascript and do the usual: if null or 0 or empty or (yeah this is where truthy/falsy gets tricky doesnt it? Is the string `"Non"` falsy?)'.

What you're presumably looking for is either:

```
if (r.isNull("fldplayersalary")) {
```

or possibly:

```
if (r.getInt("fldplayersalary") != 0) {
```

Note that `.getInt` returns `0` if the value stored for that row is `NULL`, hence, if fldplayersalary is NULL, *or* it is set to 0, that if would *not* trigger, otherwise, it would, which sounds like what you wanted.